# Importing data connection from text (Excel) FAST WAY

Tags: vba, excel, import, excel-external-data

Is there a faster way to import data from text into Excel sheet  then clicking and defining parameters. There are users who do not know how to use import wizard. Is there a possibility to do that via Macros??

Imported data is always in the same format (in notepad) and the values need to be stored always in the same range so that formula on the other sheet would work.

Thanks

Comment: This should be the kind of job that the macro recorders was intended for. Record your key strokes into a macro and run the macro for each repetition.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. You will not get a solution from scratch here per site rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by others you can easily do it with the recording. Here's a sample to satisfy your need.

```
 Dim src_file_name As String
 src_file_name = openDialog
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)).Name = "temp_text"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp_text").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & src_file_name _
        , Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("temp_text").Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "text_to_excel"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

As you mentioned you feel to ask the user to pick the text file. Just include the below method -

```
Function openDialog() As String
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

  .AllowMultiSelect = False

  ' Set the title of the dialog box.
  .Title = "Please select the file."

  ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

  ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
  ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
  ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
  If .Show = True Then
    openDialog = .SelectedItems(1)

  End If
End With
End Function
```

(Note - Don't forget to call this function above as I did.)

Comment: Thank you very much. The notepad text that needs to be imported is with a new name. It is coming via email everday. So today it is E474 and tomorow is E478. In the end i need the user to browse the document and that wizard imports it in the background. Shoould have sad that in my first post ,sry.

Comment: Added a function to do that for you. Don't forget to accept the answer. Enjoy :)